# Problem with online jQuery ajax in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, jquery

I'm trying to do an ajax call on my website but for some reason it works in all other browsers than Google Chrome. My jQuery ajax call looks as follows:

```
$(".showpopup").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var thePopup = $(this).attr("id");
    $(".popup_overlay").fadeIn("medium");
    $(".popup").fadeIn("slow");
    $(".popup").load("/dev/popup/"+thePopup);
    return false;
});
```

The problem is that when looking in firebug (in Chrome) I see that the call is made and that the return code is "200 ok", moreover I can even see the response HTML from the requested page but I just can't get the content into my `<div>` with the `.popup` class. I've tried adding a allback function to the `$.load()` function which won't fire either.

I've read the people are having trouble with this on local testing sites but this site is running online and therefore I just don't see the problem.

I've been pulling my hair out for two hours now so any help at all would be very much appreaciated! :-)

Comment: Did you see any html validation errors on your developer tools console log?

Comment: Believe it or not - firebug was the problem! As soon as I closed the firebug inspection tool it worked!

Comment: You should add your own answer for this question. In 48 hours you can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe it or not - the Google Chrome Firebug extension was the problem. I closed the Firebug console and then it worked like a charm :-)

Sorry for the inconvenience